# How can I use ruby-trello gem to send an email invitation to a user’s board?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, trello

I'm using ruby-trello gem for my rails app. I can attach users to the board, but they don’t receive an invitation to their mail. How do I send an invitation to a board to users? I add users like this:

```
  USERS_LIST.each do |mem|
    member = Trello::Member.find(mem)
    @trello_board.add_member(member, :normal)
  end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. Does the code in your question reliably and clearly demonstrate the problem you are having? If not, edit the question and add the minimal code necessary to demonstrate it. Without that you're asking us to imagine the code that fails, then guess at what the cause could be, and then the solution, which is too broad and off-topic.

Comment: It only sends an email if they aren't signed up for Trello already: https://help.trello.com/article/715-inviting-people-to-an-organization. You would need to send an email manually or programmatically, separate from the ruby-trello gem.